# Azure batch job scheduling using dot net

Tags: azure, azure-batch

Can anyone help to with azure batch - scheduling job using .net code.

My requirement is to schedule different jobs  at different date time. That is job will get executed at specified date time. Number of jobs and the batch job run date will be dynamic. It should be updated from dot net code. With this I also want to execute my logic instead of task.. how we can achieve this?

Comment: Hello, Did you look at this docs for scheduling the jobs via Azure Portal - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-job-schedule , https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/jobs-and-tasks.

Comment: Yes, I don't understand how to implement it for per job.. want to create per job dynamic scheduler